# list environment to set different paragraphs within an item

Tags: lists, environments

I'm trying to create a document with exercies and solutions. Since exercises often come in different parts (such as (a), (b) and so on), I want to use lists for the solutions. However, solutions are often complicated and need some formatting to be well understable. Therefore I need a list environment with flexible formatting such as stetting different paragraphs within an item.

I am using `enumitem`, but the inline list environment `enumerate*` doesn't accept paragraphs and seems to cause other minor problems. What alternatives do I have?

Here is a piece of code:

```
\begin{solution}
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item {Text with, separated by an empty line

    to set a new paragraph}
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{solution}
```

An this is the output I get:

[image: no paragraph is set]

Here is a full minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{amsmath,thmmarks,thref}{ntheorem}
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol}   
\usepackage{ntheorem,thmtools}
\usepackage{
    enumitem,
}

\declaretheoremstyle{plain}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,numbered=no,name=Proof]{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*),mode=unboxed]

    \item {A text

      separated by an empty line}
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Again, here is my output:

[image: no inserted paragraph]

Comment: Does it have to be an _inline_ list? The standard `enumerate` would allow paragraph breaks within items. IMHO it does not make sense to have paragraph breaks in an inline list.

Comment: @cgnieder I think you're right. Maybe I just want to _refer_ to the listed questions instead of answering them in a listed environment. I'll take council with my pillow.

Comment: Referring should be pretty straight forward using `\label` and `\ref`...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure of I understand your question correctly. Using the series concept (refer to the package documentation for further details) you can use a standard  `enumerate` environment when you need paragraphs and then `enumerate*` when you want an in-line enumeration, but using `resume=<series-name>` to keep the numbering consistent:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{amsmath,thmmarks,thref}{ntheorem}
\PassOptionsToPackage{inline}{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,MnSymbol}   
\usepackage{ntheorem,thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\declaretheoremstyle{plain}
\declaretheorem[style=plain,numbered=no,name=Proof]{proof}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}[series=a,label=(\alph*),mode=unboxed]
    \item A text

      separated by an empty line
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate*}[resume=a,label=(\alph*),mode=unboxed]
    \item A text
    \item A text
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is good and helps. But I dislike the indent and margin which comes from not using the inline environment. Is there a way to solve this, too? ("separated" should begin at the same indent as "(b)" in the line below.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for alternatives, it works with plain TeX's \item:

```
\item{1.} {Text with, separated by an empty line

    to set a new paragraph}

\bye
```

Comment: Yeah, great. TeX.